# Eclipse RCP P2 UpdateSite Repository not found

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho, p2

I am have built an Eclipse RCP Product and P2Update Site using Maven Tycho. The P2 Publisher has created a structure like below

[image: P2 Publisher Structure]

RCP Product has no problems reading it from a local directory via a file:// URL, but when I upload to FTP server with "https" URL, RCP P2 Provisioning refuses to see the repository. I get the below 
[image]

I am not able to debug the problem as to why FTP server URL is throwing No Repository found. Appreciate if any one can give some pointers on how to fix this issue. I am unable to find out if this is SSL issue.

TIA.

Comment: Coukd you give http protocol try? Die you try to directly download e.g. p2.index file from a Browser? Is it asking for an unsecure https Site Access?

Comment: the p2.index file was generated by Tycho Maven Install Command. I did try http protocol and still gave the same error.'

Comment: Does the provider "exavault.com" allow http or https access to the repository? Try it with a web-browser and download the content.jar and artifacts.jar with the browser first.

Comment: FTP protocol is not supported by p2

Comment: exavault.com allows https access. I upload the repository to FTP server as rar file then ask the user to download a local copy to get Feature update. So, which is the best server to setup Update Site?

Comment: After uploading your p2 repository files to your provider. Try to mirror (artifact and metadata) repository with the help of  [Eclipse p2 mirroring](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_mirror.html) using the same URL you provide for your update. This assures that your eclipse p2 instances can later on access the repos, if they can be mirrored successfully.